# How to fix send PHPMailer SMTP mail on GoDaddy Server 500 (Internal Server) Error

Tags: php, smtp, phpmailer

When I try to send a mail from GoDaddy Server by PHPMailer (SMTP) it shows the 500 (Internal Server) Error.

My Code Is:

```
    ini_set('display_errors', 1);
    error_reporting(E_ALL);

    require 'vendor/autoload.php';
    use PHPMailer\PHPMailer\PHPMailer;
    use PHPMailer\PHPMailer\Exception;

    $mail = new PHPMailer(true);


    $mail->isSMTP(); 
    $mail->Host = 'SERVER.secureserver.net';    // Must be GoDaddy host name
    $mail->SMTPAuth = true; 
    $mail->Username = 'EMAIL';
    $mail->Password = 'PASSWORD';
    $mail->SMTPSecure = 'tls';   // ssl will no longer work on GoDaddy CPanel SMTP
    $mail->Port = 587;    // Must use port 587 with TLS



  $mail->setFrom('EMAIL', 'NAME');
  $mail->addAddress('EMAIL', 'NAME');

  $mail->Subject = 'Mail Subject';
  $mail->Body = 'Mail Body';

  $send = $mail->send();
?>
```

It returns the 500 (Internal Server) Error.

Comment: We need to see the server side error log to solve this.

Comment: You really need to search before you post and follow links to the troubleshooting guide; Amongst other limitations, GoDaddy doesn't support TLS to its own email servers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For those who visited this page now.

**GoDaddy email doesn't support TLS**

To ensure the highest level of security for your email, TLS versions `1.0` and `1.1` are no longer supported by GoDaddy.

Ref: https://in.godaddy.com/help/tls-10-and-11-end-of-support-41090

---

In this case, use Gmail or Outlook SMTP

You may follow this guides,

- https://developers.google.com/gmail/imap/imap-smtp
- https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/pop-imap-and-smtp-settings-for-outlook-com-d088b986-291d-42b8-9564-9c414e2aa040